# Server Resources In Production M2

Tags: magento2, server-setup

What are the ideal settings (php.ini) for following in production mode Magento 2:

```
max_execution_time
memory_limit
post_max_size
upload_max_filesize
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set these value here :

```
vendor/tubalmartin/cssmin/cssmin.php
```

But this is a core file and its not good to change the core file. Whenever you upgrade Magento the change will loose.

Answer (score 0):

You may set below configuration for production. However you may change these values based on application/data size.

```
max_execution_time = 1800
memory_limit = 3G
post_max_size = 8M
upload_max_filesize = 2M (depends upon your need)
```